# What is the best way to create an array of all images found in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to create an array of all the images in a string of HTML.

I've tried using the following but it generates errors if the complete URL path is not present in the src.

```
var found = $(html).find('img');
```

Comment: so what does this string look like? and what are the errors?

Comment: The string is a standard HTML page. The error I am getting is "Failed to load resource" I appear to be getting these errors when the full path is not included in the source. IE in a css stylesheet...

Comment: What do you do with `found` later?

Comment: I loop through `found` and pick out only the images that are bigger than 100 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").each(
      function(index) {
         theArray.push( $(this).attr("src") );
      });
```

Comment: How do I pass the variable 'html' to that? 'html' is the string I need to search.

Comment: @JorgeA.Gonzalez, are you searching a string or are you searching a web page (i.e., the DOM)?

Comment: It's a string of HTML I get back from a callback function.

Comment: You could use some RegEx to parse it.  But I'd probably just add the HTML to a hidden DIV, extract the images as I've instructed, and then dump the contents of the hidden DIV.  It's not pretty, but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
var imgArray = $('img'),
    srcArray = [];

console.log(imgArray);  // array of imgs

$.each(imgArray, function() {
   srcArray.push(this.src));
});
```

Comment: `this.src` is faster and less to type than `$(this).attr(`src`);`

Answer (score 0):

Quick run down of how to achieve this:

Open with jQuery's DOM Ready function ->

```
$(function(){
```

Create the variable `found` which holds a collection of the elements.

```
  var found = $('p > img');
```

Create an empty Array to hold our results.

```
  var results = new Array();
```

Iterate through each of the elements that we `found`

```
  $.each(found, function(index,value){
```

For each 'value' (the item) that we find, we want to take the src, and push that src into the array.

```
   results.push($(value).attr('src'));
```

Erroneous closure

```
   });
```

Alert the total amount of items in the array;

```
  alert('There is a total of '+results.length+' results in the Array.');
```

Alert just the src of the 3rd item we added to the array.

```
  alert('The src of the 3rd item is: '+results[2]); //3nd item in array, indexes are 0 based
```

Erroneous closure

```
});
```

Hopefully this helps clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with simple and plain JavaScript by creating an "instant" html element:

1. Create a element
2. Insert the string as innerHTML
3. Query the node

Example:

```
var html = "<html><body><img src='/img1.png' /><br /><img src='/img2.png' /></body></html>";

var node = document.createElement("div");
node.innerHTML = html;

for(var i=0; i < node.children.length; i += 1) {
    if (node.children[i].tagName === 'IMG') {
        alert(node.children[i].src)
    };
}
```

Comment: I get `Failed to load resource` on /img1.png. Why do I get these errors on search function? Are they being validated by JS?

Comment: Here is what I get back from outputting the array "chrome-extension://gabjcfmfiiglnojdinndihaijejbefem/img1.png"

Comment: It prepends the current domain, so if you are on the chrome extensions page then this is correct. If you don't need it then split the '/' and take the last element from the array to get the file name.